# STL std::sort() uses Introsort, but how does it work?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, introsort

I don't really get the Introsort algorithm. As you can see I added the pseudocode of it. 
What is meant by the maxdepth?

What does that mean " `⌊log(length(A))⌋ × 2`"

I hope someone can explain it to me.

```
 procedure sort(A : array):
        let maxdepth = ⌊log(length(A))⌋ × 2
        introsort(A, maxdepth)

procedure introsort(A, maxdepth):
    n ← length(A)
    p ← partition(A)  // assume this function does pivot selection, p is the final position of the pivot
    if n ≤ 1:
        return  // base case
    else if maxdepth = 0:
        heapsort(A)
    else:
        introsort(A[0:p], maxdepth - 1)
        introsort(A[p+1:n], maxdepth - 1)
```

Comment: Introsort bails out on quicksort if it's taking too long and switches to heapsort. Note the usage of `maxdepth` at `else if maxdepth = 0:
        heapsort(A)`. If too deep, finish off with heapsort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your question on `⌊log(length(A))⌋ × 2`, the `⌊...⌋` bit simply means `floor`, the highest integer less than or equal to the value.

In a less *mathematical* language, it would be `int(log(length(A))) * 2`.

---

And just in case someone brings up the difference between `floor` (round toward `-∞`) and `int` (round toward `0`), it's irrelevant here as the length must be a non-negative integer. You'll still run into mathematical trouble if the length is zero but that's an exceptional case since it probably doesn't need sorting :-)

---

As to *why* `maxdepth` exists, this is obviously an algorithm based on trees - the use of `log` also supports this since the depth of a balanced tree tends to be proportional to the logarithm of the number of nodes in it.

What seems to be happening is that, if the introsort gets beyond a certain depth, it just switches over to heapsort for the remainder.

---

And, just one minor note: `std::sort()` is *not* required to use Introsort (as your title seems to imply), the standard mandates behaviour such as `at most Nlog2N comparisons, where N=last-first` but otherwise makes no demands on algorithm choice.